# BWA doesn't recognize HiC options

Tags: bwa, hi-c

I'm trying to run bwa on HiC data. This is the command I'm giving:

```
bwa mem -5SP -T0 -t4 -R '@RG\tID:\tSM:\tLB:\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:none' REFERENCE.fa PAIR1.fq PAIR2.fq
```

and here's the error message:

```
mem: illegal option -- 5
```

Supposedly, the 5SP option is for HiC data ([cite](https://phasegenomics.github.io/2019/09/19/hic-alignment-and-qc.html)), but my BWA isn't recognizing it. Anybody have any ideas? My initial thought is to update BWA to the newest version, but I don't want to mess with our replicatibility since I am new to the lab and don't want to be updating software when I don't need to. The server is a Mac Pro and bwa version is 0.7.12-r1039. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `conda` to install and test the desired version of `bwa` to test. This will not interfere with whatever version installed on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option has been added in 0.7.16a, see https://github.com/lh3/bwa/releases, so consider updating.

Comment: Thanks for providing exactly the answer needed!

Answer (score 3):

Your link with those command line options is 1 year old.  Looks like that version of bwa is 6 years old.  You probably should update.